# Applying percentage change calculation to a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to do something relatively simple in R; I am trying to compute the percentage changes from one row to the next for each component of the matrix. This is the code I am running

```
> fun <- function(x) diff(x, lag=1)/lag(x,1);
> mat <- dx[2490:2520,];
> mat <- apply(mat, 2, fun);

There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In diff(x, lag = 1)/lag(x, 1) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The R console returns this message to me, and I have no idea why. If this doesn't work, can someone point out a different way to compute percentage changes? any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `pctChange <- function(x) {diff(x)/x[-nrow(x),]*100};
pctChange(mat)` Or `library(quantmod); apply(mat, 2, Delt)`

Comment: `lag` does not shorten vectors, but `diff` does.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is `m` rows and `n` columns, and you want the output to be `m-1` rows and `n` columns, then:

```
(mat <- matrix(sample(50, 15, replace = TRUE), nr=3, nc=5))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]   28    2   21    9    2
## [2,]   18   11    8    2   24
## [3,]   21    2   20    8   21
apply(mat, 2, function(cc) (cc[-1] - head(cc, n = -1)) / head(cc, n = -1))
##            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]   [,5]
## [1,] -0.3571429  4.5000000 -0.6190476 -0.7777778 11.000
## [2,]  0.1666667 -0.8181818  1.5000000  3.0000000 -0.125
```

Or, even faster:

```
nr <- nrow(mat)
(mat[-1,] - mat[-nr,]) / mat[-nr,]
##            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]   [,5]
## [1,] -0.3571429  4.5000000 -0.6190476 -0.7777778 11.000
## [2,]  0.1666667 -0.8181818  1.5000000  3.0000000 -0.125
```